# Put an 'ok' or 'open' button in JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jfilechooser

I have used the `JFileChooser` option but by default, it shows save and cancel button. I want to put an OK button instead of save button. How do I do that?

Comment: you can change the word by type in the constructor!

Comment: *"How do I do that?"*  Why do you want to do that?  From the perspective of an end user, I detest GUIs where the programmer tries to be 'kewl' and make their GUI 'stand out' from the others.  I'd far prefer something that is 'the path of least surprise' wherever possible.  What is it about this app. that justifies breaking that principle of 'least surprise'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this one help:

```
JFileChooser j = new JFileChooser();
j.showDialog(this, "ok");
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When using one of the `showDialog()`-variants you can use

```
showDialog(Component parent, String approveButtonText)
```

with an `approveButtonText` of your choice.

If you instanciate your own `JFileChooser` use

```
setApproveButtonText(String approveButtonText)
```

to change the button's text.